# Grouped in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with dividing a string for n length strings which should be in array.
Is there any built function in Python which can do that, like for example `.grouped` in Scala?

e.g. `word= 'ABCDEFG'`, `n=3`

Result: `['ABC','DEF','G']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using simple slicing.

```py
n = 3
word = "ABCDEFG"

result = [word[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(word), n)]
```

Also worth mentioning the [`chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) function from the `more_itertools` package.